# onchange event not working in chrome but works well in firefox

Tags: javascript-remoting, chrome, onchange

Today I faced a weird issue. I have made a visualforce page containing an autocomplete box for searching. I have used javascript in my controller class and have written "onchange" event in visual force page. Onchange event is fired when the value of a textbox changes and it works well in Firefox. But the same event is not fired in Chrome. I have tried using Onkeypress and Onkeyup events but they dont fit in my requirement.
You may refer the snippet as below[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Alphesh, you can also post code directly, but you'll need to use the 'binary button' in the editor to make it visible/formatted.